# Synchronize zip-archive after removing files

Tags: zip

Using the `zip` command `zip -qrj dir1/archive.zip dir2/*.jpg`.

After removing a file from `dir2` I want to synchronize the archive using `dir2` as reference. I.e. remove the file from the zip archive as well. It seems it only adds or updates files but doesn't remove them.

Have tried `zip -qrju dir1/archive.zip dir2/*.jpg` but it doesn't remove the file.

Comment: I miss-read your question rather big in my answer :P No use here I guess, so I delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-FS` option:

> -FS
> --filesync
> Synchronize  the contents of an archive with the files on the OS.  Normally when an archive is updated, new files are added and changed files are updated but files that no
> longer exist on the OS are not deleted from the archive.  This option enables a new mode that checks entries in the archive against the file system.  If the file time  and
> file size of the entry matches that of the OS file, the entry is copied from the old archive instead of being read from the file system and compressed.  If the OS file has
> changed, the entry is read and compressed as usual.  If the entry in the archive does not match a file on the OS, the entry is deleted.  Enabling this option should create
> archives that are the same as new archives, but since existing entries are copied instead of compressed, updating an existing archive with -FS can be much faster than cre‐
> ating a new archive.  Also consider using -u for updating an archive.

`zip -qrj -FS dir1/archive.zip dir2/*.jpg`